# How repeate process of view cache creation on each dbcontext queries to db (not only at first)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, nunit

I've written test to gather some metrics about Entity Framework during first and subsequence queries.

```
...
        [Test]
        [TestCase(1)]
        [TestCase(10)]
        public void FatEF_Init(int _id)
        {
            // Arrange.
            // Act.
            _watch.Reset();
            _watch.Start();

            //Create dbContext, work with them and then dispose it.
            using (var qmsUow = new FatDbContext(_sqlConnection.ToString()))
            {
                var result = qmsUow.SomeEntities.SingleOrDefault(se => se.Id == _id);

                _watch.Stop();

                // Fill DTO.
                _info = new QueryDataDTO
                {
                    Id = _id,
                    DurationTime = _watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                };

                // Assert.
                Debug.WriteLine($"id: {_id}. {_info.DurationTime} ms.");
            }
        }
```

So, as you can see I am running my test 2 times with different params. At first call ( "cold") Entity Framework go throuth its initialisation process and cash themselves in app domain(as I understand it) and then it makes the second query in "warm" state much faster.

As result I get two execution result  (first one about  ~ 9 second, second ~ 2 ms), but i want to know average time per 10 request at first ( "cold" state).

**Q:** How I can unload and load again Entity Framework from memory between test iterations? (Or to clear view cache)

**Q**  Or Maybe it possible recreate view cache in each query?

Comment: Why are you measuring *cold start* performance? Is the context too big perhaps? If you intend to use it as a Unit of Work (which it isn't) it shouldn't contain any more entity types than those used in the UoW.

Comment: Thx for your attention. I've chosen very big dbContext specifically to get more visible results.  I really need to measure "cold" start for perfomance considiration reasons. Then I will start apply diffrent settings to it and analizing obtained results.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to unload static data is to perform initialization in a separate AppDomain and recreate it when you need it fresh. May be challenging in unit tests, never tried it.

Comment: Thx a lot, I also generaly think that it the most realistic way, but from other side i still hope  that more easy solution will be found :)

Comment: It is meaningless to perform timing measurements with a cold dbcontext. Even if you would be able to get rid of the data, every smart database would have remembered that you just asked for items and have some (intermediate) results still in memory. Even if you would do low level SQL queries the second one would be faster.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're right, but i change params between 2 queires and then also think dynamic change entities ( ie queries to diffrent tables). Actually i really need to understand how view Pre generation scenario hekp me at first query to database through Entity Framework. So i start with EF default behavior at first query ( ''cold) Thx for help